# Setting default values for associations in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, associations

Suppose that I have a has_many / belongs_to relationship between categories and articles in mongoid. That is, a category can have many articles, and an article belongs_to a category.

Is there a way I can set a default value for an article's category? That is, if I don't set the category on the article, it just assumes a certain value by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleanest way is to create your objects through a builder which would set default values if required.

Otherwise, simply override the getter

```
def category
  super || default_category
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct. It would also be possible to do it with a callback, actually modifying the document to include the category.

```
before_create do
  self.category = default_category unless category
end
```